# Why don't this two consecutive draw commands with angle generate parallel lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle

Consider the added minimal example, I was expecting it to generate two parallel lines. The ending result however is that the second line start at the end of the first in what I assume is the relative angle. I have no idea how the length is determined. I've also attached a figure of my results. So, as the title ask. Why won't this two line be parallel?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (-1.5,-0.1) -- (51:1.9);
    \draw  (1.5,-0.1) -- (51:1.9);
    \node at (-1.5,-0.1) {a};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The output of the simple code

[image]

Comment: The director vector is not the same so they are not parallel.

Comment: I'd need to read up on tikz' coordinate systems... going by the picture, is `(51:1.9)` polar w.r.t. origin? (It sounds like you want polar w.r.t. the current position.)

Comment: Oh now I get it. You need to put a `+` sign before the end point to make it relative as in `+(51:1.9)`

Comment: Be careful. Since the point `a` is not the origin, the vector `(51:1.9)` is not the director vector to the line.

Comment: @Sigur, I've placed point ``a`` just so we'll have an easy point to discuss.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Remarks

### Regrading your Question

Note the leading `+` in front of the target coordinates. To receive parallel lines you have to draw a line relative the the start point. Without the `+`-sign you specify absolute coordinates with respect to the origin `(0,0)`.

### Regarding Relative Coordinates

In a path you can specify relative coordinates in several manners. Let's draw a simple rectangle.

#### Using explicit coordinates

The simplest way using the `rectangle` macro.

```
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

Using a line to connect the edges:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) --cycle;
```

#### Using relative coordinates

With the rectangle macro:

```
\draw (0,0) rectangle +(1,1);
```

Using a line to connect the edges: Point preceeded by a single `+` are always relative to the previous declared point on the path and the pen is returned to the previous point

```
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,0) -- +(1,1) -- +(0,1) --cycle;
```

while points with two `++` are still relative the previous point on the path but the pen stays on the resulting point relative to the previous point

```
\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(0,-1) --cycle;
```

#### More about relative coordinates

If you want to learn more about relative coordinates, review section 2.15 of the current [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=31).

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-1.5,-0.1) -- +(51:1.9);
        \draw (1.5,-0.1)  -- +(51:1.9);
        \node at (-1.5,-0.1) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Nice answer. You may like to add some information about the `++` syntax ...

Comment: included a small clarification, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for your improvements. You are always welcome!